# Rails No route matches[POST] on second update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a form in Rails like so:

```
= form_for cart, as: :cart, url: backoffice_cart_path(cart) , method: :put,  html: { autocomplete: "off", class: 'cart-quoter' } do |f|
```

When its rendered it shows the following header

```
<form action="/backoffice/carts/4" ...>
```

When I update some stuff in the view I am returned to the same place, however, if I try to do the same stuff again, it throws me this error

> No route matches [POST] "/backoffice/carts/3"

Which is exactly the same previous address that was being used.

Any ideas on what it could be?

Note:

The cart object does exist from the beginning, so I can effectively update the object the first time, but sending it again the second time the router does not find the specified route.

At the beginning the form_for code was like this:

```
= form_for ['backoffice', cart],  html: { autocomplete: "off", class: 'cart-quoter' } do |f|
```

I just added more explicit code trying to force the form submission.

The route exists but just to be sure

```
backoffice_cart GET    /backoffice/carts/:id(.:format)                                     backoffice/carts#show
                PATCH  /backoffice/carts/:id(.:format)                                     backoffice/carts#update
                PUT    /backoffice/carts/:id(.:format)                                     backoffice/carts#update
                DELETE /backoffice/carts/:id(.:format)                                     backoffice/carts#destroy
```

The controller has an `update` method, no magic in there.

Comment: Please add the relevant controller code and the routes

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
= form_for cart, as: :cart, url: backoffice_cart_path(cart) , method: :put,  html: { autocomplete: "off", class: 'cart-quoter' } do |f|
```

by

```
= form_for cart, as: :cart, url: backoffice_cart_path(cart) , html: { autocomplete: "off", class: 'cart-quoter' } do |f|
```

Comment: whats the purpose to remove method type? it does not need that it should always be `method: :post` ?

Comment: rails is capable of deciding the method by it own, removing method: :put doesnot mean it is always serve post request.

Comment: Exactly, I just added it to be more explicit in case something wrong was going on.

Answer (score 0):

The form object / record will have information on its own, on whether it is a new record or a existing record. You can check it by calling:

```
cart.new_record?
```

If it returns true, then it means this form is going to perform a `POST` `/create` according to the REST resource rules. If it returns false, then it will perform a `PATCH` to `/update` (standard is now PATCH as opposed to PUT)

Ideally, you should not have `url` or `method` parameters in the form tag for a REST resource / record. You don't even need `as` here, because if `cart` is an instance of a class named `Cart`, Rails will make sure everything is treated as `cart`, parameters wise.

In the end, your tag would look like:

```
= form_for cart do |f|
  ... form stuff ...
```

I understand you're using a namespace here, `backoffice`, so you could achieve it by something like:

```
= form_for [:backoffice, cart] do |f| 
  .... form stuff ....
```

Hopefully this should fix your problem. Make sure cart is coming from a source where it will always be a ActiveRecord model. And of course, your controller needs both `create` and `update` methods.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it was at the beginning, but I wanted to change it more explicit. That's why I started adding some more parameters.

Comment: The cart existed from the beginning, its been always an update form, it never creates a new cart. It's been the weirdest thing I've ever experienced with Rails.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem is as weird as it can be.

The form has some manual input inside, like this one

```
input[type='text' value=item.net_unit_price name="cart[cart_items][][id]"]
```

One of them was written this way

```
input[type='text' value=item.net_unit_price name="cart[cart_items][price]"]
```

With some missing brackets. I fixed that difference and the controller is working correctly.

I don't fully understand why this is the solution for my problem, but it is something you should consider when encountering this kind of problem. Looks like a form that is filled with some errors brings trouble to the router, and later the controllers in rails.